# More than 4 PWM output at 25khz?

Tags: pwm, frequency

Is it possible using an arduino to control more than 4 PWM fan at 25khz ?

I have found this but 4 PWM limited with an UNO

https://arduino.stackovernet.com/fr/q/8407

An other arduino, like a 2560 could be used ?

Thanks
Best regards
Sébastien

Comment: I would like replace this : https://www.nzxt.com/products/grid-plus-v3 in my work station

Comment: See answers in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/what-is-the-frequency-of-pwm-output-on-arduino for a guide on how fast Arduino PWM can be.

Comment: You could also use timer0, but then delay and millis won't work anymore. Second option is to use a external chip. You could also use a MEGA like you suggested, or the newer ATMega328P**B** (I don't think the latter is already used in the UNOs)

Comment: why would you need individual control of the 4 fans? ... just use one PWM signal to control all four.

Comment: '328P supports 6 analogWrite() outputs on D3,5,6,9,10,11. Won't all 6 do 25 KHz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you could use a Mega. See [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25623): it explains how
you can use Timer 1 on an Uno to provide two PWM channels at
25 kHz. This is the only 16-bit timer on that board. The Mega, on
the other hand, has four 16-bit timers: Timers 1, 3, 4 and 5. These
timers are almost identical to the Uno's Timer 1, except that they
provide 3 PWM channels each. So you have potentially up to
12 PWM channels that you can run at 25 kHz.

Now, look at this [pinout diagram](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=146511.0;attach=90705). Every pin labeled `OCnx`,
where `n` is either 1, 3, 4 or 5, and `x` is a letter, is a 16-bit PWM
output. Just take the code from the answer I linked to and adapt it to
the Mega. You configure all those timers in the same way, and you set
the duty cycle for pin `OC3B` by writing to the register `OCR3B` (and so
on...).